Why do Western countries seem to think Russia would rather be defeated than use nuclear weapons?
Latest example: UK urges China to prevent its companies supporting Russia's military.
Suppose China stops its companies from supporting Russia's military. The UK's desired outcome appears to be:

China stops its companies from supporting Russia's military. Russia starts losing the war as a result. Ukraine pushes the Russians back to the border, the two countries agree to peace, and everyone is happy.

Why does the UK seem to think the above is more probable than:

China stops its companies from supporting Russia's military. Russia starts losing the war as a result. Russia decides they'd rather use nuclear weapons than lose the war, and Kyiv goes up in a mushroom cloud. This forces the US to intervene (since they allegedly have already threatened to do so if Russia goes nuclear). Russia starts losing the war even more badly, but they've already decided they'd rather use nuclear weapons than lose, so Washington DC also goes up in a mushroom cloud, followed shortly by an all-out nuclear exchange.

Although this uses a UK example, it's by no means unique to the UK, and other Western countries have expressed similar views. I am looking for an explanation as to why they do not seem to consider the second outcome very probable.
Edit to phrase this question slightly differently:

How do Western countries know that Russian leaders won't choose death over defeat?

It's happened many times before in history.
And if they do choose death over defeat, how do Western countries know they won't take the rest of the world down with them?

Why do you think that Russia would be willing to use nuclear weapons as part of a war on foreign soil? There is a major difference between losing a war on foreign soil and one that is taking place inside Russian borders. Would Russian leadership be willing to risk total destruction of Russia over Ukraine?

There are more alternatives.

@JoeW What counts as ‘foreign soil’?  There seems to be a difference of opinion on where Russia's borders are…

@gidds most of the world considers all of Ukraine including the occupied areas as not part of Russia. And I would highly doubt that Russia would risk destruction over parts of Ukraine.

I think the premise of the question is flawed: you're mixing up different meanings of the word "defeat", and the link in your recent edit shows this very clearly: When some Nazis leaders committed suicide, "defeat" meant that Germany was in ashes, was days from unconditional surrender, and was about to be occupied, with many of the Nazi leaders to be held responsible for their crimes. Nobody's going to occupy Russia or to expect its conditional surrender, and nobody's going to come after Putin (unless the Russians do it themselves), let alone after large parts of the Russian leadership.

@JochenGlueck write an answer with some evidence suggesting that then - refuting e.g. Putin when he said Russia has "nowhere to retreat" over Ukraine or similar, suggesting he views the conflict as existential.  https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/putin-says-russia-has-nowhere-retreat-over-ukraine-2021-12-21/.

@Allure: Evidence suggesting what precisely? I clearly explained why the situations are very different.

@JochenGlueck that the Russian leadership does not view losing the war in Ukraine as defeat in the Germany-sense that you described in your comment.

@Allure: I'm inclined to point out that everybody who hasn't gone completely insane can see the major differences between the two scenarios. So are you asking for evidence that the Russian leadership hasn't gone completely insane?

@JochenGlueck do you think anyone who isn't completely insane would've attacked Ukraine in the first place? If yes, are you suggesting that Russia had justifiable reasons to attack? If not, what makes you think the Russian leadership aren't completely insane?

"do you think anyone who isn't completely insane would've attacked Ukraine in the first place? If yes, are you suggesting that Russia had justifiable reasons to attack?" This is a false dichotomy. It is absolutely possible to make very unethical decisions (and also gross miscalculations) without being completely insane. (But technically speaking, you're of course right: I don't have conclusive evidence that Putin hasn't gone completely nuts. After all, I cannot look into his head.)

@JoeW, the stakes for Russia would be the degree of internal political destabilisation resulting from defeat, and the extent to which a hostile foreign bloc will then be confidently on their doorstep. Really, the only way Russia would accept defeat in Ukraine, is if the political destabilisation came first.

Who says Russia would rather be defeated than use nuclear weapons, or vice versa, please?
I suggest 'How do Western countries know that Russian leaders won't choose death over defeat?' is by no means an 'Edit to phrase this question slightly differently…' Rather, it's a diametric reversal of the Question, turning everything upside down.
Will you please edit both Question and exposition to something more useful, such as 'What's your view about Russia's leaders' preference for defeat over using nukes?'?

Frame challenge:
It does not cost UK anything to ask China to stop supporting Russian war efforts and start hindering those instead. If China does what it is asked to do, then obviously the situation on the front becomes somewhat better - Russian advance slows down maybe, perhaps it will stop altogether or even start crumbling. Perhaps there is damage to Russian political regime as well.
So for a politician, it is a no-brainer to ask. Best case, you brought home some bacon, worst case - at least you tried bringing some political utility.
I don't believe that any overt politial mechanisms are suited to deal with "worse is better" situations, such as when UK's support for Ukraine causes nuclear threats, or when a successful Russian offense causes the increase of Ukraine support. Politicians do their own job and the big picture is out of their direct scope.
It is possible there are some covert political mechanisms (схематоз, договорнячки in Russian). But since they are not public, we can only speculate about these.

I'm accepting this answer because it appears to be correct, per the answer I wrote.

Historically, the USSR (and thus Russia by extension) has held invasion of its territory as the red line for the use of nuclear weapons. Ukraine was part of the USSR but not part of Russia, which confuses the issue a bit, but the general belief is that as long as there's no appearance of the West entering Russian sovereign territory that red line won't be crossed.
'Defeat' is an interesting word to use here. No one is really talking about defeating Russia; the aim seems to be exhaust Russia so that they stop their invasion and retreat back to pre-war borders. Russia won't need to formally surrender, or even to formally sue for peace. All they need to do is go home. Putin can stay in power and save face with his people any way that he likes, and would find it difficult to justify a nuclear strike.

How would this answer change now that Ukrainian forces have been occupying Russian territory (in Kursk Oblast) for the better part of two months?

The alternative scenario that drives the question seems to misjudge the U.S. reaction. It states:

China stops its companies from supporting Russia's military. Russia
starts losing the war as a result. Russia decides they'd rather use
nuclear weapons than lose the war, and Kyiv goes up in a mushroom
cloud. This forces the US to intervene (since they allegedly have
already threatened to do so if Russia goes nuclear). Russia starts
losing the war even more badly, but they've already decided they'd
rather use nuclear weapons than lose, so Washington DC also goes up in
a mushroom cloud, followed shortly by an all-out nuclear exchange.

If Kyiv goes up in a mushroom cloud, the U.S., the U.K., and France are very likely to use nuclear weapons on Moscow, and not just "intervene", in a matter of minutes or hours. Almost all senior government officials in Russia, including Putin, half of the oligarchs, and millions of unlucky ordinary Russians end up dead.
If you opponent is crazy enough to nuke Kyiv, you have to assume that there is no limit to your opponent's perfidy and that anyone in your country or any other NATO country or allied country would be next. Nuking Moscow would be proportional tit-for-tat for nuking Kyiv that has the potential to end the regime that is doing so.
This is the basic logic of mutual assured destruction, which, for better or worse, has been the prevailing proclaimed military policy of nuclear armed countries on all sides since the Cold War.
Importantly, however, a nuclear attack whose effect is that "Kyiv goes up in a mushroom cloud" is not what Russia has threatened. It has threatened to use tactical nuclear weapons that wouldn't annihilate everyone in a major city for a presumably less epic purpose, like destroying a military command bunker or a Ukrainian nuclear power plant. How Ukraine and its allies would react to that is harder to tell and might depend upon the details.

Do you have any evidence for the statement If Kyiv goes up in a mushroom cloud, the U.S., the U.K., and France are very likely to use nuclear weapons on Moscow? The linked answer only says a conventional strike.

Also, is there any evidence that the Russian government would prefer to lose the war than MAD?

@Allure With respect to both comments, the link in this answer explains that this is the prevailing policy on strategic nuclear warfare and has been formally articulated by the USA and the Soviet Union. See specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction#Official_policy No one can know for sure if these policies would actually be followed by the people with the nuclear codes, but the credible risk that they would be deters the use of nuclear weapons.

That link actually suggests that Russia thinks they can survive a nuclear exchange: The Soviets believed they could win not only a strategic nuclear war, which they planned to absorb with their extensive civil defense planning, but also the conventional war that they predicted would follow after their strategic nuclear arsenal had been depleted

@Allure If Russia is so willing to nuke Kyiv why wouldn’t other nuclear powers not think that they are also at risk for supporting Kyiv

Also this answer makes the assumption that it's inconceivable for MAD to be preferable to defeat. I imagine it is conceivable - both Germany & Japan would likely have done it at the end of WW2, if they had nuclear weapons.

Actually, it is a stretch to assume the NATO MAD umbrella automatically stretches to Kiev.  Yes, a nuke strike on NATO territory => "very likely to use nuclear weapons on Moscow" but I see no hard reason to believe that is true, or untrue, in the case of a strike on Kiev.  It could very well escalate very quickly, but I doubt NATO's first game plan is "launch on Moscow", whereas one would expect just that if London, New York or Paris had been struck.  Probably a bit for tit for tat and then - if/when that fails to settle things - Moscow and Washington mushrooms.

I think you are wrong, but if there was such a reaction, it would be an attempted counterforce strike at strategic weapons site.

I'm skeptical too NATO would go straight to nuking Moscow if Putin nukes Kyiv. But just unloading some Tomahawks on Russia's airbases would severely cripple the Russian military. (Just see what Ukraine manages now and then with a few long-range drones, in that respect.) And then Russia would have the tough choice whether to nuke something in the West or not because they won't really have other trump cards left. I think Russia's leadership doesn't want to be in the position where they have to make that choice to begin with. @o.m. yeah, more likely.

I think discussing whether or not MAD deterrence would work or not is beside the point. The west maintain a position of strategic ambiguity on first-strike, not because they are sayin they  would definately use Nukes without it being a retaliation, but to leave enough uncertainty in the minds of enemeies as to discourage them from taking the risk. As to whether MAD would prove a sufficient deterrent - there is a reason that detractors of the policy chose the acronymn MAD, but correct or not, it is a policy the defence forces of the west have relied on for many years.

@IanSudbery that cuts to the point though. First there is an implicit assumption that Russia is rational, but there's also the argument that a rational Russia would not have attacked Ukraine in the first place, so the assumption is shaky. Second even if Russia is rational, they might feel like they have no choice, since losing the war is worse than MAD. "Why do we need a world if Russia is not in it?" and all that.

@Allure Losing the Ukraine war =! "Russia is defeated."

@ohwilleke do you have any sources for that? It seems to me that it comes down to definitions, and I'm not interested in personal definitions there - I'm interested in what the Russian leadership thinks, because ultimately they're the ones that control whether to use nukes.

@Allure Your claim that it would be viewed that way is far beyond anything that anyone in Russian leadership has ever said.

@ohwilleke that goes both ways - I don't believe the Russian leadership has ever publicly said anything about losing the war.

@Allure - My arguement is not that MAD is a good policy, but that it is the policy the west has followed for many decades. I think you are giving the wests defence policy centres too much credit.

I don't expect that Putin and his top generals would die in a retaliatory nuclear strike against Moscow. They would reasonably foresee such a strike, and take precautions by being elsewhere, or in bunkers.

It is difficult to generalize about 'the West,' but the general assumption is that Ukraine is not part of Russia and that Russia can exist without Ukraine. Therefore holding Ukraine is not a vital national interest of Russia. 'The West' may be misjudging how the Russians think about it, or they may be correctly judging that the nuclear threat is all a bluff. (Neither I nor the Western governments know the truth about what Putin thinks, and speculating about his state of mind is out of scope on this site.)
They also believe that China does not want a Russian nuclear strike, and that Russia understands that it needs Chinese support. So their confidence is higher in any slow-moving situation, where plans can be debated at length and China can intervene, while concern goes up when things happen fast. (Compare the liberation of Kharkiv -- it is controversial if Russia made serious nuclear plans then, but the possibility made the news for years after.)

Why is there an assumption that Russia can exist without Ukraine? It's more densely populated than e.g. Siberia, for example. Are you saying we can extrapolate to "Russia can exist without Siberia", ergo, an invasion of Siberia would not prompt a nuclear exchange?

@Allure: Nobody is invading Siberia, nor is such an invasion remotely plausible in the foreseeable future, so it's essentially irrelevant whether Russia would defend Siberia with nukes.

@Allure, Russia did exist without Ukraine since the breakup of the Soviet Union. To Western eyes, the problems Russia had since then (crash marketization, corruption, autocracy, demographic decline) do not seem to be caused by the lack of Ukraine. Nationalist Russians might see it differently, of course.

holding Ukraine is not a vital national interest of Russia. Russia doesn't want Ukraine. It wants Crimea, which is strategically important for their national security due to the Svestapol navy base. Russia has never let go of its claim over it, not its navy let go of it even post-USSR. The history of Crimean political activity by the majority Russian speaking (mostly retirees from the Black Sea navy) also clearly highlight - from Referendums demanding autonomy, to declaration of independence, to demanding dual citizenship with Russia - Ukraine's weak political claim over it.

Source for "Crimeans preferring Russia over Ukrane" (if you doubt the referendums and elections of pro-Russians in Crimea) - a 2013 US Gallup polls (PDF) asked Crimeans, Regardless of your passport, what do you consider yourself? - and only 15 % identified as "Ukrainian". Even amongst those considered ethnic Ukranians in Crimea, only 66% identified themselves as a "Ukranian" national! (1/2)

And a 2014 US Gallup poll often partitioned and displayed results of the poll as "Ukraine (Exclusive of Crimea)" to highlight the disproportionate difference of views between Crimea and the rest of Ukraine. Interestingly, 73.9 % of the Crimeans agreed with the view that Crimea's becoming part of Russia will make life better for me and my family. (Note: In 2014, Russia annexed Crimea). (2/2)

@sfxedit Also only 63% of the ethnically Russian population of Crimea saw themselves as Russian and only 40% in total, the rest being split on Ukranian, Crimean and Crimean-Tatars. Also in 2013 only 23% were in favor of being part of Russia. If anything they wanted to be an autonomous republic within Ukraine 53%

@haxor789 We can nitpick on the individual questions and their response, but you will find that overall, both the 2013 and 2014 opinion polls indicate a strong preference towards Russia amongst the majority in Crimea, over Ukraine. When considered with the demography of the region (majority ethnic Russians, majority Russian speaking population) and all the referendums for independence and autonomy, and Crimeans electing a pro-Russian Crimean as President (which forced Ukraine to abolish the Crimean constitution and presidential post) - all show how weak Ukraine's political claim is on Crimea.

@haxor789 And note that I am making a distinction between legal and political claim. Legally, Crimean territory belongs to Ukraine. Even Russia recognized this in their treaties with Ukraine. Russia claims the terms of the recognition included sovereign guarantees to not ally against Russia and, importantly, leasing of the Svestapol naval base to Russia. With political pressure, Russia renewed the lease so it can hold the base until 2042. But look at the foolishness - even before the lease expired, even before consolidating political support in Crimea, Ukrainians foolishly applied to NATO.

@sfxedit Yes Crimea has it's own history, from being an Autonomous SSR in the early Soviet Union due to a national minority of the Crimean Tartars. After WWII they were accused of crimes during the war and deported, revoking the ASSR status and downgrading them to a Russian Oblast, until 1954 when they became a Ukranian Oblast, until the dissolution of the USSR when they reestablished themselves as an ASSR, with a lot of back and forth between Crimea and Ukraine in the 90s with regards to independence or autonomous status within Ukraine ultimately settling for the latter.

@sfxedit 2/ And yes that involved an episode where a pro-Russian president held a referendum for more autonomy, dual Ukrainian and Russian citizenship and more power to the president, which resulted in a conflict between president and parliament of Crimea in which Ukraine intervened temporarily governing Crimea, before again settling for an autonomous republic within Ukraine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Crimea_(1992%E2%80%931995) . So yeah Crimean autonomy and independence movements aren't unheard of.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"holding Ukraine is not a vital national interest of Russia" - that proceeds from the wrong assumption. The demonstrable ability to hold captured territory against the West is now the issue, not the intrinsic value of Ukraine itself.

@Steve, by that reasoning, any nuclear power can do whatever it says it needs to do. That would be wrong as soon as there is more than one superpower. Geopolitics talks about the stability-instability paradox.

@o.m., in the past the situation was managed by accepting so-called spheres of influence. But my point is just that the intrinsic value of mainland Ukraine is not the one issue at stake.

Russian Billionaire Survival Likelihood
The chance that powerful Russians (Putin, Generals, Billionaires) will die in a conventional loss is extremely small. Ukraine does not seek to conquer Russia - they won't ever be marching on Moscow.
The chance that powerful Russians will die after a nuclear strike is much higher. The West may do a retaliatory nuclear strike, or a conventional decapitation strike, or provide significant quantities of long range weapons to Ukraine, or fear of Western response might trigger a coup, or... any number of things.
In an oligarchy, the question is always "how does this impact the oligarchs?" -- and a conventional loss impacts them very little, while a nuclear strike significantly increases the risk to their lives.

I don't see how this answers the question, which phrased alternatively is *how do you know the Russian elite doesn't prefer death to defeat?".

@Allure - If a subset of the Russia elite has gone insane and would rather die than fail to conquer their neighbor, I would expect the much larger group of not-insane Russian elite to stop them with a coup or assassination or similar.

Curiously if you look at sources like https://www.cirsd.org/files/000/000/009/75/401141581c665840ebdf7c1304da4a9486211f99.pdf, it says "Ukrainian entry into NATO is the brightest of all red lines for the Russian elite, not just Putin" -- so I would like to see why you think part of the Russian elite would stop the other part from "going insane".

@Allure They do not want USA nuclear weapons 500km away from Moscow. Note, as there were Soviet nuclear weapons 2000km away from Washington, Washington has nearly done a preemptive nuclear attack. Against Moscow, not against Cuba.

There are different ways to take this question.  At the lower end of the scale - "why doesn't Russia nuke something minor in Ukraine", I believe this has been asked already and is a dupe.
Let's look instead at the higher end of the scale, instead "Washington DC also goes up in a mushroom cloud", aka let's radioactivize the UK with our glorious Poseidon, which is not a dupe.
Let's flip the question around and away from Russia.

The US military contemplated using nukes in Vietnam.  Would it have been reasonable to do so, when US vital interests were not at stake?
If the US had invaded Cuba - beyond what it did in Bay of Pigs - would it have been reasonable for them to nuke it if they did not get their way?
The US almost escalated to a nuke war during the Cuban Missile Crisis.  Was it reasonable for it to do so, when they had equivalent missiles in Turkey?  Kennedy, imho, has been judged way too kindly by history.
But even that was in the context of the Cold War, when both systems had an avowed aim to destroy the other.  All that's being requested of Russia is not to invade a neighbor.
Let's say in 2030, a putative Amerika Uber Alles POTUS invades Cuba to bring it back within its Monroe Doctrine sphere of influence, away from the godless Commies.  And threatens a nuclear war if it doesn't get its way.  Would you be asking if the world was being unreasonable because it expected better?

Russia would be totally in its rights to escalate to nukes if NATO attacked Russian territory.  And even direct NATO on Russian engagement on Ukrainian territory would be foolhardy, coming from NATO.  Let's even include a concerted effort to regime-change Putin out.  Is anyone seriously proposing any of that?  The USSR long supported the VC in Vietnam and it - reasonably enough - did not anticipate the US have a nuclear hissy fit to endanger the entire planet just because of that, ultimately peripheral, conflict.
This would be Putin's Russia behaving even more irresponsibly that the USSR ever did, when the stakes aren't near as high.  Stuff about the UK pressuring Chinese companies don't seem all that relevant to what Russia does with its nukes and seem more intended to justify Russia's threats.  Threats which waaay predated this UK pressure, and, IIRC, started up fairly on, with Putin promising "such consequences that you have never encountered in your history" as early as February 2022.
Plus, this is assuming Putin is irrational, while an assumption of rationality would be that Putin would play brinkmanship games as far as they go, short of actually pulling the nuclear trigger.
If not "blame the victim", this looks much like "pity the perp".


Question:
Why do Western countries seem to think Russia would rather be defeated than use nuclear weapons?

While the threat of nuclear escalation remains a serious concern in any conflict involving major powers, the assumption that Russia would rather avoid using nuclear weapons is grounded in rational calculations. The doctrine of Mutual Assured Destruction, the risks of geopolitical isolation (Russia's two most important allies, China and India who are actively keeping their economy on life support have both publicly warned Russia not to use nuclear weapons in Ukraine. ), the limited strategic benefits, and the domestic repercussions all make the use of nuclear weapons an undesirable option for Russia. Moreover, historical precedent suggests that even during moments of extreme pressure, Russia has shown restraint in its use of nuclear force. While these assumptions are contingent on rational decision-making, they reflect a belief in the overwhelming costs of nuclear use, a belief that continues to shape Western strategies in managing the conflict with Russia.

Do you have any source for Russia's two most important allies, China and India who are actively keeping their economy on life support have both publicly warned Russia not to use nuclear weapons in Ukraine?

Death IS defeat...
And your (linked) example of the Nazis is somewhat off. The Nazis operate upon a racist theory of extinction (either us or them) and thought of their opponents as less-than-human. And given how far that ideology permeated common life, how many were actively or passively involved in genocide and crimes against humanity, they had no reason to expect mercy and likely wouldn't have given it to themselves. So suicide might have looked like the less painful death, where death was non-negotiable.
And even they got away fairly lenient compared to their crimes. A short time occupation a few higher ups were killed and then things got back to normal or even better than before...
While in terms of Russia it's an aggressive war, I don't intent to downplay the war crimes already committed, but it's not (yet) the-end-of-the-world level serious. Like there is a good chance that if Russia retreats to its borders makes some concessions for the damage done and supplies a plan for how to keep a stable peace, maybe keeping a low profile for a few years and they'd be fine for the most part.
Also it's not that it's the first time that they've done that either:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Russia#Russian_Federation_(1991%E2%80%93present)
and they've largely gotten away with most of those things and might have even gotten away with taking Crimea.
So it's somewhat like "If you're planning to commit suicide, why would you set the alarm clock for tomorrow". Like if Russians had a death wish and such a deep hatred of everyone else that they would take their own demise just to spite someone else, then why all that hassle? Why not a nuclear first strike on Washington or whatnot to begin with? No explanation, no build up of tension, using the element of surprise to do as much damage as possible and expect to be wiped off the map in the response...
Now fair enough if you plan to take your life, you're likely in such a disturbed state of mind that an outsider doesn't need to expect rational actions. So one might be very wrong with that assessment but taking nibbles when you could bite, makes more of an impression of someone who's testing out boundaries and how far they could go before facing a reaction, rather than someone who has nothing to lose and goes in do or die.
While with what they are doing right now, they draw all eyes on them, making surprise attacks impossible. They make NATO empty its old stock, test it in real-life conditions, while resupplying and getting combat ready after a long time of peace where loads of people talked about whether such excessive military spending is even useful for anything anymore.
So if a do-or-die full scale, total war, with nuclear annihilation, trying to make as much damage with your death as possible, was their goal, then these moves would make no sense.
The threat of such a move was usually applied defensively where it makes a lot more sense. So "If you threaten to wipe us out, you'll pay for that with massive death and destruction of your own country". In an insane way that makes sense. While there was always the afterthought of whether you'd actually do that as it makes no difference to the dead if more people die, it's also not really as if you'd have a strong incentive to let your curiosity get the better of you when it comes to figure out how Schrödinger's "End of the World (as we know it)" would behave if you peeked.
Now could take the route of arguing that the threat of nuclear annihilation pertains to the defense of their territory and that now parts of Ukraine are their territory (whether the rest of the world agrees with that or not). But what that effectively means is that Russia would either risk all of Russia for territories of Ukraine that they for the longest time didn't claim and showed no interest of claiming (at times even explicitly codified in treaties that they wouldn't claim them) or have that entirely backfire and be required to argue that some parts of Russia are "more Russia" than others.
So that's a very dangerous game of testing the waters on the threat of nukes. And that's not the only angle where they play a dangerous game of nuclear chicken, because on the other end they claim that they are at war with NATO (which they aren't!), but if they proceeded to use nukes and/or attack a NATO country or use nukes and have that interfere with a NATO country, then it would be NATO's turn to respond. And as apparently diplomacy, sanctions and whatnot are without much effect and don't increase willingness to negotiate, they'd likely either not react and show weakness inviting further expansion and crimes undercutting the the red line that is NATO itself ("attack one of us and you'll deal with all of us") or they need to come to this countries defense and respond on par or even escalate the conflict to deter further action.
And so far Russia is losing offensive troops by more or less their own choice (they could at any point withdraw from the conflict). While if they actually get in conflict with NATO things could get much more serious. Like throughout the entire cold war both sides tried to avoid any such direct conflict, because it would test the defensive threats with potentially horrible consequences for both sides. So as much as Russia likes to shit talk about being in conflict with NATO and sell it to their domestic audience, they probably still have qualms actually getting in conflict with NATO as either way that's going to be nasty and the full scope of that cannot be foreseen. But if both sides play some power games where they don't want to show weakness, that would end in destruction massive destruction. So death AND defeat.
So yeah currently Russia is dancing dangerously close to red lines and moves its own red lines further which makes NATO have to dance around theirs, so that's a very dangerous game, but so far Russia would have more to lose than to win actually further escalating this conflict.
Now of course this constant talk about fighting NATO, pretending as if one could use nukes and have an advantage of that instead of risking a much larger and more devastating conflict, a war mentality of death and defeat already happening and a narrowed frame of reference in which further destruction would run into a saturation of how awful it could get, a propaganda that might rest on success and strength and where showing weakness is fatal and a general willingness shown in other wars to just throw bodies at the problem and devalue life, could lead to an acceptance of death rather than living (with defeat, but mostly at all).
But currently it doesn't make sense or the impression that Russia is so desperate.
And that's not talking about China who probably likes it that Russia is keeping the West busy, testing the waters for how much Western security guarantees are worth and what would happen if they'd claim Taiwan (which unlike Russia they already claimed (unilaterally), but haven't enacted the claim), but who probably see no benefit in a larger nuclear war in which they likely would also be a target.
So as of right now it doesn't make much sense for Russia to go all in over territory that they have just claimed.

if Russians had a death wish and such a deep hatred of everyone else that they would take their own demise just to spite someone else, then why all that hassle That's not the idea. The idea is that if Russia views the conflict as existential, then they won't be willing to accept defeat. This is not the same as actively seeking death.

@Allure The vowel of nuclear super powers is that if one drops the bomb, all hell breaks lose. So that's somewhat of a suicide bomb, in that you do damage but also more likely than not you're going to die. So that works on some level as a surprise attack doing massive damage and die, it works to some extend as a defensive weapon in the sense of "if I've nothing left to lose I might as well blow stuff up", but it doesn't work as an offensive threat. Like "Really you want to kill yourself if you don't get that"?

Russia has some very densely populated cities, like Moscow and St Petersburg. This country has large, very sparsely populated areas spreading over Siberia and few very densely populated areas, making it a good target itself. Look into the density map.
France maintains the fourth most significant nuclear force in the world, and many of its missiles are submarine-based. The UK also operates submarines with nuclear warheads. I have seen some Russian PR talking about the EU not having an early warning system good enough (the USA has one, though). Still, is Russia sure they know the location of all these submarines at the time of the attack? Can all ships be down in time, or are they more likely to pretend the submarines do not exist?
I really do not understand how those urging to launch Russian nuclear weapons toward the "collective West" manage to take these facts out of consideration. Even if the USA does not strike, for two cities, French rockets should be enough. They seem never to say a single word about these weapons, as if Russia would launch their missiles, devastate Europe, then trumpet some propaganda towards China and India that they have just done the most right thing in the world - and that's it.
Other EU countries, like Germany, Belgium, Italy, and the Netherlands, participate in NATO's nuclear sharing program, which means they host U.S. nuclear weapons on their territory but do not have control over them. It is still a big optimism to assume the USA will not allow these rockets to respond, as they can say afterward, "We only authorized European rockets to take off and have not fired our main arsenal yet; let's all stop here and stay in friendly peace from now on."
Of course, a head of state can theoretically order about anything, including firing Russian rockets at Moscow (while having Kyiv in mind, semantic paraphasia), but at some point, his own team may refuse to carry suicidal orders.

This does not seem to answer the question, which assumes the Russian leadership is desperate/unhinged enough to choose death over defeat. In other words, it's assumed they're fully aware that if they use nukes, they'll trigger a nuclear counterstrike that kills every Russian - but they also prefer that result to losing the war. The question asks how one can rule out this possibility. It does not ask whether Russia will also be wiped out if they use nukes.

But this is the reason, kind of important, not to fire nukes to the enemy.

No, this is predicated on the assumption that you value your own life and are afraid to die. Sufficiently desperate/unhinged people will not care. Unless you are postulating that the soldiers will refuse to obey orders - but any soldiers who have doubts about firing the weapon would not be placed in command of them in the first place. See e.g. https://www.heraldscotland.com/news/14222242.meet-submariner-fingers-trident-nuclear-launch-trigger/

@Allure, Well, then first prove that the political and military leaders of Russia are actually unhinged and desperate. Except for the usual propaganda on this from expected quarters, what other reliable sources makes you convinced about this?

@sfxedit see source in this comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88512/why-do-western-countries-seem-to-think-russia-would-rather-be-defeated-than-use/89261?noredirect=1#comment392655_88630

@Allure Ok, I finally understood your point. That source says many of the same things that I too try to say here (with limited success). But I differ with the authors point of view - he sees it only as a desperate action of a country pushed into a corner, where as I see it as a very rational course of action for a country pushed into a corner. Despite some initial missteps, Putin has acted very ably and rationally to protect Russian interest, and continues to do so. (Compared to Putin, Biden seems like a senile old fool still living in the cold war era, with an irrational hatred of Russia).

FWTW, if we be believe Woodward's book, one detail missing from Allure's answer:

U.S. intelligence officials saw China as having the most influence over Russia, and Biden called Chinese President Xi Jinping about the need for deterrence, Woodward wrote.
Xi agreed to warn Putin, according to the book. Biden and Xi met and agreed in November 2022 that “a nuclear war should never be fought” and noted their opposition to the use or threat to deploy nuclear weapons in Ukraine, a White House statement said at the time.

The latter kind of statement is not exactly new though. A quick search for that phrase shows up in a P5 joint statement from Jan 2022, just before the Russian large-scale invasion.
China probably sees South Korea getting nukes next in any nuclear escalation scenario. (Public opinion there is already over 60% (or even 70%) in favor.) Likewise the number of Western states on the nuclear threshold is greater than Russia+China allies. China is also worried by Japan's large pile of nuclear material, IIRC.  Taiwan's GDP is greater than Israel's BTW. If they decided to get nuclear weapons, any plans of China invading will probably gain them a radioactive heap at best, plus millions of casualties on the mainland. (Taiwan reportedly did have an incipient program in the 1970s.)


It's happened many times before in history. [Link to Nazi suicides].

No country leaders committed suicide (just) after losing a border province, AFAIK. You are confusing vastly different levels of defeat.
Despite the Kursk incursion, there are still substantive restraints on what Ukraine can do with Western weapons. I don't see the West approving of Ukraine taking Moscow, even if that were somehow militarily feasible, which right now is surely not. Which, BTW, is in part due to the relatively limited supply of weapons they received, and the drawn out deliveries. BTW, this was in part due to (at least partly or temporarily) successful Russian bluffing that they'd hit Western countries e.g. if they delivered tanks to Ukraine. This story has been repeated a few times with other systems.
Likewise your assumption in the comments below that Russia expects to be nuked if it nukes Ukraine is iffy, despite one answer claiming that's what's going to happen. They are certainly worried about losing some standing, extra sanctions, and possibly a cooling of the relations with some of the few friends they have. (I guess North Korea would applaud though.)
TBH, China would indeed be a in a tough position how to make good on their denunciation of nuclear war: they can't quite afford to just stop buying Russia oil and gas, but they also have to worry about losing clout in the "Global South" if they do nothing once the basis of non-proliferation goes out, basically, with a P5 initiating first use against a non-nuclear (and smaller) country.
It's not a given, IMHO, that the West would even follow with conventional strikes on Russian forces anywhere, but that's surely something the West is perhaps willing to let Russia think might happen, without being explicit about it. IIRC they threatened to remove all constraints on Western weapons given to Ukraine. Which is not much of threat if Russia would be willing to glass Ukraine with dozens of nukes. But that would ruin their claim of being liberators of "Malorussia" (= "little Russia") etc. Too few nukes used might not tip the balance, and too many would be a genocide difficult to blow off in propaganda (anybody would still be willing to listen to, i.e. outside Russia).
THB, if Russia glasses Ukraine, I have a feeling at least Iran would get nuked soon thereafter, probably by Israel. "Give war a chance" will get its ultimate embodiment as "give nukes a chance" in international relations.

I don't understand this answer, unless you are assuming that Russia needs China's approval to use nuclear weapons (do they?).

@Allure: approval no -- but they probably worry how much China will still support them if they go against their wishes. TBH, China would probably be in a tough spot as they can't just stop buying Russian gas & oil. But even if they just stop selling them golf carts, 50cc engines, and the like, Russia would still suffer a bit on the front line.

I don't see it then - in the scenario I'm envisaging, if Russia uses nuclear weapons, it's because they're OK destroying the world. China might not even exist in a post-nuclear war world; it's irrelevant if China supports them (or not).

In the same vein, Russia is probably not going to exist either after pushing that button. Does the approval of anyone (other than God, I suppose) matter if you're dead? I don't see it.

Based on this source it seems the idea is that there are ways in which Russia can escalate before Kyiv goes up in a mushroom cloud. Therefore, right now, it is OK to escalate until Russia signals decisively that any further escalation leads to nuclear war.

Gerhard Mangott, a security specialist at the University of Innsbruck in Austria, said in an interview he also thought it was possible, though in his view not likely, that Russia's response could include some form of nuclear signal.
"The Russians could conduct a nuclear test. They have made all the preparations needed. They could explode a tactical nuclear weapon somewhere in the east of the country just to demonstrate that (they) mean it when they say we will eventually resort to nuclear weapons."
...
In the case of Britain, Moscow was likely to declare that London had gone from a hybrid proxy war with Russia to direct armed aggression if it allows Kyiv to fire Storm Shadow missiles at Russia, former Kremlin adviser Sergei Markov said on social media platform Telegram on Friday.
Russia was likely to close the British embassy in Moscow and its own in London, strike British drones and warplanes close to Russia, for example over the Black Sea, and possibly fire missiles at F-16 warplanes that carry the Storm Shadows at their bases in Romania and Poland, Markov predicted.

Reading between the lines, it seems that the West thinks that if they further escalate the conflict (most recently by allowing Ukraine to use Western-missiles within Russia) then Russia will likely escalate, but will crucially not use strategic nuclear weapons (the kind that wipes out cities and kills millions of people) immediately. Instead Russia will take certain actions that indicate that they are serious about using nuclear weapons eventually. When that happens, that's when one can stop escalating. Until then, @alamar is right that taking actions that increase the likelihood of Russia losing this war is nearly costless.
Update: The reaction to Putin changing Russia's nuclear doctrine reinforces the above. Source.

Fabian Hoffmann, a doctoral research fellow and defence expert in Oslo, said he did not believe Putin's comments could be ignored, but that it was important not to overreact.
"Russian nuclear use is not imminent," he said on X. "Concern is warranted only when Russia signals actual preparations."
Hoffmann said next steps could be removing warheads from storage and pairing them with delivery vehicles for a tactical strike, before ratcheting up preparations for large-scale nuclear use by readying silos and putting bombers on alert - all of which U.S. intelligence agencies would detect.
And Russia security expert Mark Galeotti wrote: "Talk is easy and has political impact, but evidence of actual willingness to use nuclear weapons is both absent and something we can detect if it ever happens."

Assuming Hoffman and Galeotti's positions are mirrored by actual leaders (who surely have received intelligence of the same), then the West appears to believe that if Russia is serious about using nuclear weapons, they'll be able to detect it. Once they do, they still have time to stop escalating.
Update #2: It looks like some Western leaders think that Russia is not serious about escalating, and that even if they did escalate, it's an acceptable risk. Source.

Alexander Stubb, Finland's president, and Lithuanian Foreign Minister Gabrielius Landsbergis said in interviews that Putin's threats to escalate had proven largely empty, and that there was little indication that would change if the U.S. allowed Ukraine to strike Russia with longer-range missiles.
Even if Moscow escalated the conflict, Landsbergis said, that would be a necessary risk to take as "there's a war to win". The worst consequences out of all the possibilities, he said, would be if Ukraine lost the war.

The last statement makes it seem like Landsbergis thinks mutual nuclear annihilation is preferable to Ukraine losing the war.
Update #3: It looks like Western intelligence agencies operating in Russia did think it was possible Russia would use nuclear weapons in the event of a major defeat.

By September 2022, US intelligence reports deemed “exquisite” revealed a “deeply unnerving assessment” of Putin — that he was so desperate about battlefield losses that he might use tactical nuclear weapons in Ukraine.
Based on the alarming new intelligence reports, the White House believed there was a 50% chance Russia would use a tactical nuclear weapon — a striking assessment that had skyrocketed up from 5% and then 10%, Woodward reports.
“On all channels, get on the line with the Russians,” Biden instructed his national security adviser, Jake Sullivan. “Tell them what we will do in response,” he said, according to Woodward.
The book recounts a tense phone call between Defense Secretary Lloyd Austin and his Russian counterpart in October 2022.
“If you did this, all the restraints that we have been operating under in Ukraine would be reconsidered,” Austin said to Defense Minister Sergei Shoigu, according to Woodward. “This would isolate Russia on the world stage to a degree you Russians cannot fully appreciate.”
“I don’t take kindly to being threatened,” Shoigu responded.
“Mr. Minister,” Austin said, according to Woodward, “I am the leader of the most powerful military in the history of the world. I don’t make threats.”

This suggests that the answer to the OP is the West (thanks to intelligence agents in Russia) think there is a real chance that if Russia loses the war, then they will use nuclear weapons; but they also think they can intimidate Russia into not using nuclear weapons.

But then Russia will have hit the NATO bloc, and then NATO either have to fold - potentially bankrupting confidence in the bloc, and politically destabilising the regimes which suffer the hits which they don't respond to - or further escalate in "self-defence" (i.e. in reinforcement of their offensive acts) which is the thing you are saying NATO don't have to do. (1/2)

Russia won't escalate to nuclear through sustaining any specific attack - it will escalate to nuclear only so as not to lose against the West, regardless of what attack exactly is causing them to lose. And as you say, there are so many ways to escalate before then in a way that will smash the furniture of Western globalism. (2/2)

@Allure Weird framing. For the record Russia started an aggressive war against a likely weaker neighbor. The West tries it's best to stay out of this conflict only supplying Ukraine with weapons but not otherwise engage in hostile conduct towards Russia. On the contrary the West has for the longest time imposed restrictions on Ukraine with regards to targets that would be unreasonable for any other country defending itself, specifically to NOT escalate with Russia. It's just that Russia apparently is not seeing that as deescalation but actively tries to exploit these consessions as weaknesses.

@haxor789 I don't understand your comment, since I don't disagree with most of it, and yet I see no relevance with the question or this answer.

@Steve But then Russia will have hit the NATO bloc This answer quotes several escalatory scenarios that don't involve hitting NATO directly. Like, if Russia uses a tactical nuclear weapon in Ukraine, NATO does not have to respond (or shut up shop). But they'd presumably take it as a warning that any further escalation can cause Kyiv to go up in a mushroom cloud, which is when they stop escalating.

@Allure Because you frame it as if the West is escalating this conflict when it's largely Russia which is the actor here. Also I guess there was another question about tactical and strategic nukes and the distinction is limited and often insignificant. So even a tactical nuclear attack could be seen as a nuclear attack and warrant a response with strategic nukes. So it's more of a not-even-once situation. Also if radioactive fallout hits Poland that's potentially escalating to WWIII and Moscow going up in a mushroom cloud. These are no win scenarios and escalation towards them is not good...

@haxor789 unless you are one of the people who believe that the solution to guns is more guns, I don't see how you can see this as the West not escalating the conflict.  And I don't see your point about Moscow going up in a mushroom cloud. Anyone using nuclear weapons is presumably ready and willing to die.

@Allure Russia is trying to forcefully, by means of warfare and war crimes, to integrate another country. Apparently playing some cold war politics without the pretense of ideology (beyond nationalist imperialism) and without even attempts to sugar coat that with regards to international law. And the reaction of the west has been diplomatics, sanctions and mild support for Ukraine. What was the reaction of Russia? "We're fighting NATO now"... If anything the lack of action is apparently seen as weakness rather than as willingness to come to a resulution, so what should the response be?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If the Russian leadership wants to take the mineral wealth of Ukraine, it would not be sensible to irradiate the area.
With one of the main exports of Russia being oil and gas, the move to renewable energy will diminish its income from that. Of course, they are increasing the move to renewable energy because of embargoes against themselves.

A nuclear bomb doesn't really make a city totally uninhabitable. Why Can People Live in Hiroshima and Nagasaki Now, But Not Chernobyl?.


China said many times, they won't support the Russians any more if they use nuke. 2. Also the BRICS countries would strongly dislike with an ally using nukes. 3. Ukrainians consider the Russians orcs, Russians consider the Ukrainians as border russians, their own people, under hostile political influence. They won't kill their own people. 4. They are about to win even without nukes.


I think, Western politicians understand, that RF can anytime use nuclear weapons and start WW-3. And some of them speak about it, for example Donald Trump. But what is solution for this issue? The current situations is the same as Sudeten crisis in 1938. Then politicians such Neville Chamberlain decided to make peace providing A. Hitler, what he wanted, Sudetenland to prevent war. Did it make peace? You know, it didn't, the war would start next year. But there are elections in many countries this year, for example in the USA. The main issue is, that many voters think the same way, as Neville Chamberlain and his supporters thought, that it's possible make peace to provide RF president, what he wants. So if US Democrats support idea about possibility of using RF the nuclear weapon, they may loose the current election. That is why such idea isn't provided by Democrats politicians in the USA. The same issue is in France and other European countries. Currently ruling parties cannot speak about it, because they may loose election and have other internal politic issues. That is the answer for this question.

The problem with the Hitler analogy is that
(a) Putin does not have any Hitlerian agenda; (b) Putin has missile and nuclear weapon technology capable of ending all the civilised world which Hitler did not; (c) the West has a more recent history of audacity in threatening Moscow and then backing down, without Moscow becoming emboldened in aggression; and (d) it cost the European empires that confronted Hitler everything to do so, and they all forfeited to the power of the US afterwards, which is the real reason they didn't confront Hitler until they felt suicide was certain otherwise.

What about agenda. The main difference between Hitler and Putin is, that Hitler provided his agenda in public, but Putin doesn't or does partially. But the goals are the same. First, Hitler wanted to unite all Germans in Deutsche Reich and Putin wants the same for Russians. The difference is, that in Putin agenda Ukrainians and Belorussians are also Russians. I think, he thought that way in 2022 and according to such thought there would be no resist in Ukraine. But as we know, he was wrong.  Second goal for Hitler was to get lebensraum for Germans. Putin and his supporters want the same.
